# Enabling OData service available in next S/4 version

Tags: s4sdk

I'm running SAP S/4 Hana 1709, but it seems that `API_OPLACCTGDOCITEMCUBE_SRV` is avaiable since 1711, according to https://help.sap.com/doc/ce01d82756b947a1a043a5d5a3204226/1711%20500/en-US/WN_CE1711_EN.pdf . I can't find it here: https://help.sap.com/doc/b870b6ebcd2e4b5890f16f4b06827064/1709%20000/en-US/WN_OP1709_EN.pdf

Is there a way for me to obtain this service and install on 1709? I couldn't find another way to get all types of accounting documents using other VDM services and I believe it would be possible with that one. In theory, assume I can't upgrade from 1709 to 1711, but would like to use just that service.

Answer (score 1):

1711 is a Cloud release (SAP S/4HANA Cloud 1711), whereas 1709 is an On-Premise release (SAP S/4HANA 1709). There is a difference in the scope of the two releases.

Is your request about making `API_OPLACCTGDOCITEMCUBE_SRV` available in On-Premise release?

In general, `API_OPLACCTGDOCITEMCUBE_SRV` (https://api.sap.com/api/API_OPLACCTGDOCITEMCUBE_SRV/overview) is part of Scope Item `Accounting and Financial Close (‏J58‏)` (https://rapid.sap.com/bp/#/scopeitems/J58).

Comment: Yes, I would like to use it on the On-Premise release.

Comment: Do you have any more pointers on how I could install it on the On-Prem version?

Comment: As mentioned in the above documentation, this service is available only in SAP S/4HANA Cloud, and therefore, it is not possible to use it in On-Premise version.